Bazel "zip" executable fails to create output
I am following a bazel tutorial that ends up with a "zip" command.
When I execute it - I end up with an error.
I am running on a mac laptop.
I have tried multiple variations, so I am sharing just the latest one.
Here is the rule definition
def _archive(ctx):
    out_file = ctx.actions.declare_file(ctx.attr.out)

    args = ctx.actions.args()


    args.add(ctx.attr.out)
    args.add_all(ctx.files.files)



    ctx.actions.run(
        executable = "zip",
        arguments=[args],
        inputs=ctx.files.files,
        outputs=[out_file],
        use_default_shell_env = True,
    )
    return [DefaultInfo(files=depset([out_file]))]

archive = rule(
    implementation = _archive,
    attrs = {
        "files": attr.label_list(allow_files=True),
        "out": attr.string(mandatory=True),
    },
)

Here is the usage
load(":archive.bzl", "archive")

filegroup(
    name = "text_files",
    srcs = [
        "file1.txt",
        "file2.txt",
    ],
)


archive(
    name = "archive",
    files = [
        ":text_files",
    ],
    out = "all.zip",
)

Here is the command I am using
bazel build archive

And here is the error I am getting
$  bazel build archive                                                                             
INFO: Analyzed target //:archive (0 packages loaded, 4 targets configured).
INFO: From Action all.zip:
  adding: file1.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: file2.txt (stored 0%)
ERROR: <redacted>/bazel-playground-2/zip_custom_rule/BUILD:12:8: output 'all.zip' was not created
ERROR: <redacted>/bazel-playground-2/zip_custom_rule/BUILD:12:8: Action all.zip failed: not all outputs were created or valid
Target //:archive failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.151s, Critical Path: 0.03s
INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal, 1 darwin-sandbox.
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully

Debugging and log prints all show everything is at it should be.
When I implement a macro using genrule it works fine
def archive(name, files, out):
    native.genrule(
        name = name,
        srcs = files,
        outs = [out],
        cmd = "zip -j $@ $(SRCS)",
    )

How can I change my rule implementation to make it work?

The problem is that the out attribute should be an output (file) rather than a string:
def _archive(ctx):

    args = ctx.actions.args()
    args.add(ctx.outputs.out)
    args.add_all(ctx.files.files)

    ctx.actions.run(
        executable = "zip",
        arguments = [args],
        inputs = ctx.files.files,
        outputs = [ctx.outputs.out],
        use_default_shell_env = True,
    )
    return [DefaultInfo(files = depset([ctx.outputs.out]))]

archive = rule(
    implementation = _archive,
    attrs = {
        "files": attr.label_list(allow_files=True),
        "out": attr.output(mandatory=True),
    },
)

You can see the command line that bazel uses with --subcommands:
out as a string:
zip all.zip file1.txt file2.txt
vs
out as an output (file):
zip bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/all.zip file1.txt file2.txt
Also note that zip embeds timestamps in the archive, making the output non-deterministic. Also, relying on the system zip is not hermetic. Consider using rules_pkg at https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg which has the pkg_zip rule.

Amazing!!! Thank you so much. I'll also notify the tutorial author.
